# How to get a returned primary key after using executesql to insert a record

Tags: web2py

I am wondering how I can use `executesql` to communicate with a table not managed by web2py, and insert a record and get the generated key from the insert.

If that is not possible, is there are to just ask DAL for a cursor to use for a query and allow me to ask that cursor the `cursor.lastrowid`.

I am pretty sure I can use `executesql` for my SELECT and UPDATE statements - just not the INSERT statements where I need to get the PK back.

I am not interested in portability beyond MySQL for this code as I am grafting a some intricate legacy code into a web2py application without a complete rewrite.  This legacy code needs to work across several Python web frameworks.  I can abstract the connection/cursor easily but not change the entire data model for each new framework.  The work is all done as long as I make my own pymysql connection - but I really want to share the connection that Web2py already has.

Answer (score 0):

So I dug around, looked through the pydal code and came up with this solution:

```
 sql = 'INSERT INTO Users ...'
 parms = {'name': 'chuck'}
 db._adapter.execute(sql, parms)
 new_key = db._adapter.lastrowid('Users')
```

It of course zooms right past the official abstraction, but even though I only needed MySQL, I have a feeling this would work with many of the adapters.  The `table` parameter to `lastrowid`  (i.e. 'Users') is ignored in the MySQL DAL implementation but needed for others.  I included it for completeness in my own code but only tested on MySQL.  How you do placeholders for the parameters is up to you as it is adapter specific.

For me, it is far preferable to making and managing my own database connection.

Answer (score 0):

To query and update the web2py db outside of web2py, I do the following:

### pre-requisite

pip install pydal

change to web2py directory where you have gloun folder.

Here is the rough python psuedocode:

```
from pydal import DAL, Field
from gluon.validators import *
from gluon.tools import Auth, Crud, Service, PluginManager

db_name = "path/to/your/db.sqlite"
db = DAL('sqlite://' + db_name)

# for some reason, you need to define the table
try:
    db.define_table('your_table',
    ...
    )
except Exception as ex:
    pass

rows_to_process = db(db.your_table.your_query).select()
for row in rows_to_process:
    # modify the row as per your requirement
    db(row).update(your_row_changes)
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a legacy database then check out [Legacy databases and keyed tables](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables) on the web2py book. By disabling migrations and providing a compatible table definition, you can link pyDAL with your preexistent table and thus take advantage of the DAL capabilities.

Actually it makes no sense to wrap your database with pyDAL if you're just going to call `executesql()`, because there's no abstraction at all. You're dropping all the features that makes the package a Database Abstraction Layer. Instead, just use directly the database driver of your choice (probably pymysql or MySQLdb).

Hope this helps.